# Ruby: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, nomethoderror

```
class Member
  def initialize(name,score)
    @name = name.capitalize
    @score = score
  end

  def to_s
    "Hello, my name is #{@name} and my score is #{@score}. Make sure to give me a good rating!"
  end
end

class Contest
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
    @members = [] 
  end

  def join(user)
    @members << user
  end

  def rate_up
    puts "#{@name} just got a rating!"
    @score += rand(5)
    puts "Now my score is #{@score}. WHEEEEEEEE"
  end

  def rate_down
    puts "#{@name} just got a rating!"
    @score -= rand(5)
    puts "Now my score is #{@score}.....WTF"
  end

  def standing
    if @score >= 15
      puts "I got #{@score}! People love me!"
    elsif @score < 15
      puts "How did I only get #{@score}? WTF? Yall must be blind."
    end
  end

  def begin
    puts "#{@title} is about to begin! There are #{@members.size} participants this year!"
    @members.each do |person|
      person
    end
    @members.each do |person|
      person.rate_up
      person.rate_down
    end
    @members.each do |person|  
      person.standing
    end
  end
end

member1 = Member.new("jh", 6)
member2 = Member.new("is", 8)
member3 = Member.new("sw", 8)
member4 = Member.new("yh", 7)
member5 = Member.new("ws", 6)
member6 = Member.new("sm", 5)

contest1 = Contest.new("BestOfSIS")

contest1.join(member1)
contest1.join(member2)
contest1.join(member3)
contest1.join(member4)
contest1.join(member5)
contest1.join(member6)

contest1.begin
```

When I run this in Terminal I keep getting the following error:

```
BestOfSIS is about to begin! There are 6 participants this year!
2.rb:48:in `block in begin': undefined method `rate_up' for #<Member:0x007fa04b8340f8 @name="Jh", @score=6> (NoMethodError)
    from 2.rb:47:in `each'
    from 2.rb:47:in `begin'
    from 2.rb:73:in `<main>'
```

So I'm guessing there's something wrong with the method 'rate_up' but I can't figure out what.

Another question: Could I have the '@members' array initialized and the 'join' method defined under class 'Member' as opposed to class 'Contest'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like `rate_up`, `rate_down` and `standing` are meant to be methods on `Member`, but they're in the `Contest` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Member class should be

```
 class Member
  def initialize(name,score)
    @name = name.capitalize
    @score = score
  end

  def to_s
    "Hello, my name is #{@name} and my score is #{@score}. Make sure to give me a good rating!"
  end

 def rate_up
    puts "#{@name} just got a rating!"
    @score += rand(5)
    puts "Now my score is #{@score}. WHEEEEEEEE"
  end

  def rate_down
    puts "#{@name} just got a rating!"
    @score -= rand(5)
    puts "Now my score is #{@score}.....WTF"
  end

  def standing
    if @score >= 15
      puts "I got #{@score}! People love me!"
    elsif @score < 15
      puts "How did I only get #{@score}? WTF? Yall must be blind."
    end
  end   
end
```

and your contest class should be

```
class Contest
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
    @members = [] 
  end

  def join(user)
    @members << user
  end

def begin
    puts "#{@title} is about to begin! There are #{@members.size} participants this year!"
    @members.each do |person|
      person
    end
    @members.each do |person|
      person.rate_up
      person.rate_down
    end
    @members.each do |person|  
      person.standing
    end
  end
end
```

now

```
member1 = Member.new("jh", 6)
member2 = Member.new("is", 8)
member3 = Member.new("sw", 8)
member4 = Member.new("yh", 7)
member5 = Member.new("ws", 6)
member6 = Member.new("sm", 5)

contest1 = Contest.new("BestOfSIS")

contest1.join(member1)
contest1.join(member2)
contest1.join(member3)
contest1.join(member4)
contest1.join(member5)
contest1.join(member6)

contest1.begin
```

and it's getting output

```
irb(main):127:0> member1 = Member.new("jh", 6)
=> #<Member:0x007f78f175e5d8 @name="Jh", @score=6>
irb(main):128:0> member2 = Member.new("is", 8)
=> #<Member:0x007f78f17428d8 @name="Is", @score=8>
irb(main):129:0> member3 = Member.new("sw", 8)
=> #<Member:0x007f78f1729090 @name="Sw", @score=8>
irb(main):130:0> member4 = Member.new("yh", 7)
=> #<Member:0x007f78f1706f68 @name="Yh", @score=7>
irb(main):131:0> member5 = Member.new("ws", 6)
=> #<Member:0x007f78f16dd078 @name="Ws", @score=6>
irb(main):132:0> member6 = Member.new("sm", 5)
=> #<Member:0x007f78f16b7710 @name="Sm", @score=5>
irb(main):133:0> 
irb(main):134:0* contest1 = Contest.new("BestOfSIS")
=> #<Contest:0x007f78f16967b8 @title="BestOfSIS", @members=[]>
irb(main):135:0> 
irb(main):136:0* contest1.join(member1)
=> [#<Member:0x007f78f175e5d8 @name="Jh", @score=6>]
irb(main):137:0> contest1.join(member2)
=> [#<Member:0x007f78f175e5d8 @name="Jh", @score=6>, #<Member:0x007f78f17428d8 @name="Is", @score=8>]
irb(main):138:0> contest1.join(member3)
=> [#<Member:0x007f78f175e5d8 @name="Jh", @score=6>, #<Member:0x007f78f17428d8 @name="Is", @score=8>, #<Member:0x007f78f1729090 @name="Sw", @score=8>]
irb(main):139:0> contest1.join(member4)
=> [#<Member:0x007f78f175e5d8 @name="Jh", @score=6>, #<Member:0x007f78f17428d8 @name="Is", @score=8>, #<Member:0x007f78f1729090 @name="Sw", @score=8>, #<Member:0x007f78f1706f68 @name="Yh", @score=7>]
irb(main):140:0> contest1.join(member5)
=> [#<Member:0x007f78f175e5d8 @name="Jh", @score=6>, #<Member:0x007f78f17428d8 @name="Is", @score=8>, #<Member:0x007f78f1729090 @name="Sw", @score=8>, #<Member:0x007f78f1706f68 @name="Yh", @score=7>, #<Member:0x007f78f16dd078 @name="Ws", @score=6>]
irb(main):141:0> contest1.join(member6)
=> [#<Member:0x007f78f175e5d8 @name="Jh", @score=6>, #<Member:0x007f78f17428d8 @name="Is", @score=8>, #<Member:0x007f78f1729090 @name="Sw", @score=8>, #<Member:0x007f78f1706f68 @name="Yh", @score=7>, #<Member:0x007f78f16dd078 @name="Ws", @score=6>, #<Member:0x007f78f16b7710 @name="Sm", @score=5>]
irb(main):142:0> 
irb(main):143:0* contest1.begin
BestOfSIS is about to begin! There are 6 participants this year!
Jh just got a rating!
Now my score is 10. WHEEEEEEEE
Jh just got a rating!
Now my score is 9.....WTF
Is just got a rating!
Now my score is 12. WHEEEEEEEE
Is just got a rating!
Now my score is 9.....WTF
Sw just got a rating!
Now my score is 11. WHEEEEEEEE
Sw just got a rating!
Now my score is 7.....WTF
Yh just got a rating!
Now my score is 10. WHEEEEEEEE
Yh just got a rating!
Now my score is 6.....WTF
Ws just got a rating!
Now my score is 10. WHEEEEEEEE
Ws just got a rating!
Now my score is 9.....WTF
Sm just got a rating!
Now my score is 9. WHEEEEEEEE
Sm just got a rating!
Now my score is 6.....WTF
How did I only get 9? WTF? Yall must be blind.
How did I only get 9? WTF? Yall must be blind.
How did I only get 7? WTF? Yall must be blind.
How did I only get 6? WTF? Yall must be blind.
How did I only get 9? WTF? Yall must be blind.
How did I only get 6? WTF? Yall must be blind.
=> [#<Member:0x007f78f175e5d8 @name="Jh", @score=9>, #<Member:0x007f78f17428d8 @name="Is", @score=9>, #<Member:0x007f78f1729090 @name="Sw", @score=7>, #<Member:0x007f78f1706f68 @name="Yh", @score=6>, #<Member:0x007f78f16dd078 @name="Ws", @score=9>, #<Member:0x007f78f16b7710 @name="Sm", @score=6>]
```

Answer (score 1):

rate_up is on the Contest class and your calling it on the Member class because @members is a collection of the member class.  If you move that method to the Member class your code would work.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, there is a problem with the methods `rate_up`, `rate_down` and `standing`: They are members of the `Contest` class, and you try to apply them on `Member` instances. Just move them to `Member` and this will be ok.

For your second questions, you could have the `members` array and the `join` method defined under Member, but you have to make `members` a class attribute (`@@members`) so all members share the same.

It's possible, but not recommended because you cannot have two contests at the same time. Plus, the separation of concepts is bad in this case, because a member should only worry about himself and not about the contest.

Hope this was clear and answers your questions.